# Does reciting and listening to the Holy Quran have equal rewards?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, reward

If I don't know how to read Arabic language and just listen to the Holy Quran or recite the Holy Quran by following the audio.

Does these these to acts have equal rewards?

Answer (score 0):

Allah has sent this book so that people understand it. When they will do that, it will effect their actions and make their lives better.

[Quran says](http://quran.com/38/29)

> [This is] a blessed Book which We have revealed to you, [O Muhammad], that they might reflect upon its verses and that those of understanding would be reminded.

Reading or listening the Holy Quran without understanding defeats the very purpose of this book.

Comment: I think understanding the Qur'an is clearly the most important thing that we should do, but i won't say that it's meaningless to recite the Qur'an without knowing the meaning -- yet. Reciting/Listening the Qur'an is a great interaction with the Qur'an, and it helps memorizing a lot, too.

Comment: @allKid: Sorry for being extreme, but I think its not only meaningless but a ridicule of this great book to use it for any other purpose

Comment: Anyway, the Qur'an isn't a mere book. I love listening to Al-Afasy/Ahmad Saud's recitations for Surah Ar-Rahman. Not just that, I learned arabic faster because i'm used to reading it, i can read quickly and i'm also already accustomed to the grammar. I'm not trying to pick a fight here, by the way :) It's just that i think it's not proper to treat the Qur'an as a mere book -- It's not even originally a book.  Umar Ibn Khattab and thousands of others - who doesn't even understand Arabic properly were stunned at listening the recitations of the Qur'an.

Comment: Well, i think the best way to interact with the Holy Qur'an is to read it in Arabic + read it in a language you understand + listen to it.